# Go back to unvisited page on IOS

Tags: ios, navigation, back

I am unfamiliar with IOS development, so probably a simple question: is it possible that the user presses the "back" button on the top, and go to a (so far) non-visited page?
Here is the picture:
[image]

On window "1" user presses a button, the next window is "2". But here, if user presses the "back" button, go to page "3" (which was never opened so far)?

Thanks

Comment: Have you considered that redefining the back button may be confusing to the user?

Comment: It's ok, screen "1" is a special page, which should never appear after startup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply redefine the back button by creating a new one in your second view controller like this :

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIButton *backButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 60.0f, 30.0f)];
    [backButton setTitle:@"Back" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [backButton setTitleColor:self.view.tintColor forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [backButton addTarget:self action:@selector(pushToNextController) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    UIBarButtonItem *backButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:backButton];
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = backButtonItem;
}

- (void)pushToNextController {
    UIViewController *thirdViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"thirdViewController"];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:thirdViewController animated:YES];
}
```